# Что быстрее\лучше arr или .split()

Tags: jquery

Есть набор символов, допустим такой.
`var test = '1234567890'`
Он будет где-то использоваться, но он должен быть массивом.

Как будет лучше\быстрее использовать "разделение"?

**Вариант первый:**
Изначально использовать массив

```
test = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0];
```

или

**Вариант второй:** Использовать строку, но делить `.split()`'ом на массив

```
test = '1234567890';
test = test.split(''); // [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
```

Comment: Ну, если логически подумать, то что лучше "готовый искомый формат" или "некий формат преобразованный в искомый"? Вроде ответ очевиден.

Comment: конкретно в таком виде, в некоторых реализациях может не быть разницы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если какой-то набор *должен быть* массивом, нет причин делать его не массивом и выполнять *дополнительные* операции.